# Is it inefficient to load drawable directly through xml?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Actually I've made a gradient in `drawables` then loading it into background through xml . So what I'm asking is it it a good practice to do so or if not then how to load bitmap efficiently to background programmatically ?

By the way it's the layout of mainScreen.

XML

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
**android:background="@drawable/gradient"**
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's just as efficient.

There's not much difference after the project is compiled, and the benefits of doing it with XML including saving your time and avoiding coding errors (there are so many wrong ways to do it programmatically).

Also, unless you are doing something many many times (like inflating a layout 100s or 1000s of times in 1 view), even a small performance difference is negligible.

Comment: Actually it's the background of mainlayout

Comment: Yes it's only 1 operation so the difference will be negligible, if there is any difference at all. It would be much more inefficient to spend time doing the same thing programmatically when the XML is here to allow the compiler to do it for you.